# extract matched line from text file

Tags: java, text-files

> a:b:c:d:e
>
> bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
>
> ccc:ddd:eee:fff:ggg

I have a textfile content above. I am trying to compare my user input with the text file. For example

> cc:dd

When it is found, I need to retrieve the entire line. How can I retrieve the line which my user input? I have tried using `while(scanner.hasNext())` but I could not get my desire outcome.

Comment: can you post the entire code?

Comment: what are you searching with? just "cc:dd" , or more strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With standard Java libraries:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
String word = "abc";
Scanner scanner = null;

try {
    scanner = new Scanner(file);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
   //handle this
}

//now read the file line by line
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if(line.contains(word)) { 
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
scanner.close();
```

Comment: Thanks. Was what i was looking to display.

Comment: You need to close the scanner. Also, unless "handle this" includes throwing an exception, your code risks using a null scanner.

Comment: True, we need that memory, so I edited the code to close the scanner. Returning from `catch` is also fine in case of FileNotFoundException to avoid NullPointerException.