# How to use Scanner to read file and pass it to a method in Java

Tags: java, file, parameters, io, java.util.scanner

I am confused with how to use Scanner to read a file (given in command line argument), and use the information from that file in a method. What's the best way to do this?

I know there must be numerous errors in my code. i.e. Which type of parameter shall I pass to the method, string or file? I have commented my questions in the code. Many thanks!

```
public class Read {
int [] store;

public Read() {
    store = new int[200];
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File inputFile = new File (args[0]); //shall I declare a File variable here?
    Read readFile = new Read(); 
    readFile.doSomething(inputFile);//Should the parameter of doSomething be String type? 
}
public void doSomething (String inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner sc;  //I intend to use the info. from the file to do something here
    sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(inputFile));
    while (sc.hasNext()){
        .....
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255231/extract-matched-line-from-text-file
I'm sure, you'll find your answer there.

Comment: But I don't think I can declare a file as: File file = new File(arg [0])? I am confused with how to get the file "mentioned" in the command line argument.

Comment: Yes if you pass file name as `main()'s argument`.!!!

Comment: How about the parameter in the doSomething method? doSomething (File inputFile) ? somehow it looks strange to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to pass `String` means file path to the method in that sense after reading from file the `Objects` gets garbage collected after the execution of method while in main method you may want to perform some other stuff and `File` object remain accessible until the execution of main method.

***What if*** you want to read more than one file and you are passing multiple command line argument ? So passing `String` to method sounds convenient as it will allow you to manage File object.In this situation creating `File` Objects and than passing it to method becomes more time consuming.

So it Should be...

```
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Read readFile = new Read(); 
            readFile.doSomething(args[0]);
            readFile.doSomething(args[1]);//You can read multiple files
            ....
        }
        public void doSomething (String inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
            File inputFile = new File (inputFile);
            //Read File With Scanner
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the way I wrote it in my code is definitely wrong.. eclipse prompted an error saying something like "parameter in doSomething is not applicable". Can you help to figure out a way to fix it?

Comment: So I should change it to public void doSomething (File inputFile) {..}? It looks odd to me as I have never used a File as a parameter yet..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it that way, but then you'll have to pass the filename into the commandline when starting the program. Like this:

java [program] [filename]

Another solution is hardcoding:

File inputFile = new File ("filename");

Answer (score 0):

As stated above these are the two ways but note your harcoded file must be present in the project where your packages reside.